# How to handle mouse click in CefSharp to navigate back and forward

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp for Windows Forms and I'm having an issue with implementing the mouse back(XButton1) and mouse forward (XButton2) event to navigate through the browsing history.

I tried the following code but the MouseClick event does not seem to be triggered:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CefSharp.WinForms.Example
{
    public partial class BrowserForm : Form
    {
        private readonly ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

        public BrowserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Text = "CefSharp";
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com")
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            };

            browser.MenuHandler = new MenuHandler();
            browser.MouseClick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Button pressed: " + args.Button.ToString());

                if (args.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.XButton1))
                {

                    if (browser.CanGoBack)
                    {
                        browser.Back();
                    }
                }
                else if (args.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.XButton2))
                {
                    if (browser.CanGoForward)
                    {
                        browser.Forward();
                    }
                }
            };
            toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled across it via Google so thought it would be worth providing an answer. If you implement `IContextMenuHandler` you can control the `ContextMenu`. The two links below demo what's required (and some other useful features).

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/935d3900ba2147f4786386596b62339087ff61b0/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs#L15

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/c18f951a97a515df112d67775c767d4222f88c23/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L31